# Good and/or standard notation for the abelianization of a Lie algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, soft-question

I'd like to solicit good notations for the abelianization of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$. One could write $\mathfrak g/[\mathfrak g,\mathfrak g]$, or even $H_1(\mathfrak g)$ but I'd like something that is relatively compact. I've been using $\mathfrak g_{ab}$, but that strikes me as a bit ugly.

Comment: I write $G^{ab}$ in the case of groups; what is so ugly about it?

Comment: Possibly the mismatch of the font. 

Comment: \mathfrak h, perhaps?

Comment: Maximal semisimple quotient is $\mathfrak{g}^{\rm{ss}}$, so for maximal abelian quotient why not $\mathfrak{g}^{\rm{ab}}$? (Note: Roman font for superscript, not italics.)

Comment: Yeah, maybe changing the font is the simplest answer.

Comment: Concerning use of fonts in math symbols, a good rule of thumb is to use \text{xyz} or the like in math mode when the expression 'xyz' abbreviates an actual word like 'abelian' (especially if more than one letter occurs).   Similarly, LaTeX allows you to define your own math operators like \Hom or \Ext, to make these look better in math mode.   (Anyway, the original question is of marginal interest for MO.) 

Comment: I have seen $G/G'$ for groups, and $g/g'$ for Lie algebras. The notation $G'$ corresponds
to the name "derived group".  Concerning the derived series of Lie algebras , the
quotients are often also denoted by $g/g^{(1)}$, $g^{(1)}/g^{(2)}$ etc.